# Doubt parameterization

Tags: graphing-functions, parametrization

Good afternoon guys, I'm studying some math and I came across a problem. It is necessary, from a graph obtained through experiments, to carry out the parameterization of this one. Honestly, I did not quite understand what he wants with this parameterization. Follow the graph below (on the logarithmic scale).

[image: enter image description here]!]

Intuitively, I thought of this parameterization as a way to describe the graph mathematically, for that I divided it into 2 regions of the domain and for each one I found a corresponding function, for example, in the first region, I found a first degree equation (a and b would be the parameters?) and so on. Does it have anything to do with it? If not, what would this parameterization be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A good idea is to approximate your graph at the first part with Least Squares. For the second part, try to approximate by a exponential function. After doing that, just remember that you are in a log-scale and transform that

Comment: So, briefly (in this case), is the parameterization really finding the parameters needed to "write" the experiment mathematically (in the form of functions)?